# Socket.SendAsync wrong arguments

Tags: c#, sockets

I am currently studying ASP.NET MVC and encountered a problem. In the lecture that I am learning from they use a method from the `Socket` class - `SendAsync`, but when I try to use it, it asks for only one argument of type `SocketAsyncEventArgs`, whereas in the lecture it asks for two arguments - one `ArraySegment<byte>` and a `SocketFlag` `Enum`. How is this possible? My project is targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1

```
public class ConnectionHandler
{
    private readonly Socket client;

    private readonly IServerRouteConfig serverRouteConfig;

    public ConnectionHandler(Socket client, IServerRouteConfig serverRouteConfig)
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.serverRouteConfig = serverRouteConfig;
    }

    public async Task ProcessRequestAsync()
    {
        string request = await this.ReadRequest();

        IHttpContext context = new HttpContext(request);

        IHttpResponse response = new HttpHandler(this.serverRouteConfig).Handle(context);

        ArraySegment<byte> toBytes = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.Response));

        await this.client.SendAsync(toBytes, SocketFlags.None);

        Console.WriteLine(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Response);

        this.client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    }
```

Comment: Why not ask the person who provided you with that lecture?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync(v=vs.90).aspx), the `SendAsync` method was born in the `.NET Framework v3.5`, whose syntax has not changed ever:

```
public bool SendAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
```

So: either the lecture is wrong, or it's not referring to the `SendAsync` method of the `Socket` class.

However, if you look at the `Send` method, [there's a close-enough overload:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0ef12h(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
public int Send(IList<ArraySegment<byte>> buffers, SocketFlags socketFlags)
```

Comment: It turns out my project had to be a .NET Core one and not a .NET Framework one. Thanks for the help.